# Outline works, but badly

Tags: modeling, rendering, topology, freestyle

I'm very new at Blender but have (or had) a pretty extensive knowledge of 3dsmax.  So I've managed to make this shape, and even managed to do outlines to make it look like a drawing, which is what I'm going for.  But as you can see Blender has taken it upon itself to add some lines where there shouldn't be any, most notably between hole three to hole four. I made this by making a cube and then making a bunch of smaller cubes and then difference-booleaning them out.

[image: my rendering]

**Q:** Any way to convince Blender that there shouldn't actually be lines where it mistakenly drew extra lines?  Or do I have to paint them out using Photoshop?

Comment: Hello :). How did you generate the outline? Using freestyle lines? Consider [sharing the file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), there might be multiple reasons.

Comment: It is hard to answer without seeing the actual topology. If you have n-gons or superimposed edges, that might throw off the freestyle engine. Please share a wireframe view or even your file as suggested

Comment: @Gorgious i bet, the topology is exactly what you see.  These lines are generated for holes inside n-gons.

Comment: Check section "Edge Mark" or "Face Marks" https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_set.html

Comment: Well that's easy enough...here's a link.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lljtxfw79prmi9/Supra%20wiring.blend?dl=0
But really it's just a cube with a bunch of boolean cut-outs via smaller cubes...nothing complicated at all.

Yes, I did use freestyle when rendering, I didn't know of any other ways.  I will look into Edge Mark and Face Mark though.

Comment: Well I found the section where you can choose what sort of freestyle lines you want...I tried them all and the one I want is Crease.  I'm not sure why these extra lines are showing up though, by the definition of Crease on the link vklidu sent me it says it marks edges with angles greater than the crease angle, so why would these no-angle surface lines show up at all?

I could select each line and edit the Face Marks, and I may end up doing that, but is there an easier way? This drawing is fairly simple, but I would hate to have to do this for something complex.

Comment: Sorry for a late attention, next time if you want to notify someone directly start comment with @username Thank you

Answer (score 3):

*This was an wild hunting ... uf :)*

The issue comes from N-gon faces generated by the *boolean operation*.
When model consists from quad or tris faces it works fine.

**Solution** is to add a [**Triangulate Modifier**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/triangulate.html) at the end of modifier stack like so:

[image]

[image]

[image]